# JavaScript base type is `instanceof` derived type's constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have a `cat` which inherits from `animal`.

I'd expect the `cat` to be an instance of its constructor and the `animal` constructor.

The `animal` is an instance of the `cat` constructor as well though.

```js
var animal = {};

var cat = Object.create(animal);

console.log('cat instanceof animal.constructor: ' + (cat instanceof animal.constructor));
console.log('   cat instanceof cat.constructor: ' + (cat instanceof cat.constructor));
console.log('animal instanceof cat.constructor: ' + (animal instanceof cat.constructor));
```

Why is the `animal` an instance of the `cat`?

Comment: Try `console.log(cat.constructor, cat.constructor === animal.constructor);`

Comment: @4castle Thanks, but _why_ are they equal?  I'm not understanding how my derived type and my base type have the same constructor.

Comment: `cat` doesn't actually have its `constructor` property defined, so when you try to access `cat.constructor`, it uses the prototype object's `constructor` value.

Comment: @4castle OK, so the `Object.create` method will set the new object's prototype but will construct it using the `Object` object's constructor?  Does that mean that it's created in two parts, make the objects and then set its properties?

Comment: We don't know what constructor it *actually* uses. We just know that it inherits the `constructor` property from the object you use to call `Object.create`. Try doing `console.log(Object.create(null).constructor);`

Comment: @4castle Aye, `null` has an `undefined` constructor.  Is the constructor property useful at all?  If I called an object's constructor with a `new` then I wouldn't get an instance of the object, I'd get some other constructor from the prototype chain.

Comment: Exactly. And yes, the `constructor` property is very very rarely used in practice, as is the `instanceof` operator. Most style guides will tell you not to use them.

Comment: @4castle.  Thanks, that clears things up a bit. Is `Object.create()` recommended for using?

Comment: Yes, `Object.create` is very useful. Some people even prefer it to using the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The code below might make you understand this concept.

There is a difference between `instanceof`, `typeof` and `constructor`

- `instanceof`: checks for the whole chain
- `Object.prototype.constructor`: returns a reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object
- `typeof`: return the data type of whatever is considered

Now in your case: check comments

```
var animal = {}; //animal is an object
//animal.constructor is a parent Object constructor function

var cat = Object.create(animal);
//cat is an object created using animal object
//cat.constructor will also return parent Object constructor because.
//To remember this just remember that right side of instanceof always needs to be callable (that is, it needs to be a function)

console.log('cat instanceof animal.constructor: ' + (cat instanceof animal.constructor));
//this will return true as animal.constructor is nothing but parent Object constructor function and every object is instanceof that parent Object()

console.log('   cat instanceof cat.constructor: ' + (cat instanceof cat.constructor));
//this will also return true for the same reason as mentioned above

console.log('animal instanceof cat.constructor: ' + (animal instanceof cat.constructor));
//this also has the same reason
```

Comment: Is this line correct:  "`constructor`: just returns whatever constructed that object".  It seems that this isn't the case as the `cat` constructor is the `Object` constructor.

Comment: I should better rephrase it @BanksySan